# handling leading zeros in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a field1 that should not be more than 7 characters. The remaining characters in field1 should be filled with leading zeros.

If field1 is 1 then it should be converted to 0000001. 
If field1 is 21 then it should be converted to 0000021.

How do i do this in C#. Please help.

Comment: Is field1 a text box? Any printf-style formatter will allow you to specify leading 0s and output a string, which you could stick in the text box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a number and you want a string representation of 7 digits, pretty simple.

```
1.ToString("0000000");
```

Say you have any particular string and you want to pad it to 7 characters, and those characters happen to be *same* character, you can do that, too.

```
1.ToString().PadLeft(7, '0');
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a [format specifier](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/):

```
 string x = string.Format("{0:0000000}", 21);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
5.ToString("D7")
```

And to prevent having integers with more than 7 characters, modulo can be used like this:

```
(123456789 % 10000000).ToString("D7")
```

Modulo should be faster than cutting of additional characters in the resulting string.

Thus every integer will result in a 7 character string filled with up with zeros.